# Checking if all entries in a 2d Boolean array are true/false using a method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, boolean

I'm working on a project but I feel stumped on this particular section. I need to create a method that returns a boolean value true if all entries in a 2d array are false, and returns false when as little as 1 of those values is true. currently, my code inside the method resembles this:

```
int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < lightArray.length; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j <lightArray[0].length; i++) {
        if (lightArray[i][j] == false) {
           counter++;
           if (counter == lightArray.length * lightArray[0].length) {
              return true;
           }
        }
        else {
           return false;
        }
     }
  }
```

My initital thought was that i would use a 'counter' variable so that the if statement would only return true if there was a 'counter' for every value in lightArray. After testing, it doesn't seem to register when all values are set to false.

I also tried a version of the code where this section

```
if (lightArray[i][j] == false) {
           counter++;
           if (counter == lightArray.length * lightArray[0].length) {
              return true;
```

}

just read as this:

```
if (lightArray[i][j] == false) {
              return true;
```

with no 'counter' variable involved at all, but when that code is in place, the method returns true as soon as it hits a single false value.

Is there another way that I am just not thinking of that I can check every value in the 2D array before returning a boolean?

Comment: *"the method returns true as soon as it hits a single false value."* Have it do the opposite: return `false` as soon as it hits a single `true` value. If you go through the entire array without that happening, then you know that it contains only `false` values.

Comment: wow yeah thanks I should have seen that, and I appreciate the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the logic like you have should be in this form:

```
loop{
    if (negative_condition) return false;            
}
return true;
```

Notice that `return true` is outside of the loop.

In your case you have nested loop which should looks like this:

```
loop{
    loop{
        if (negative_condition) return false;  
    }          
}
return true;
```

Looking at the above pseudo code, your Java code should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lightArray.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <lightArray[0].length; j++) {
       if (lightArray[i][j] == true) return false;
    }
 }

 return true;
```